# Issue accessing service setting from an executable running as a start up task

Tags: azure, startup

I'm relatively new to Azure development and need some help overcoming the following predicament:
I have an executable that I need to run as part of my Azure service startup. The executable needs access to one of the service's application settings. 
So I added the following to my csdef (the batch script just runs the executable with output redirected to a file):

```
<Startup>
 <Task commandLine="StartupTask.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="background">
     <Environment>
         <Variable name="Var">
             <RoleInstanceValue
               xpath="/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/ConfigurationSettings/ConfigurationSetting[@name='SomeAppSetting']/@value" />
         </Variable>
      </Environment>
 </Task>
</Startup>
```

Adding the task caused the deployment to fail and after much hair tearing I realized it was because SomeAppSetting value was too long (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2013/07/30/windows-azure-role-recycling-due-to-setting-more-than-256-character-in-environmental-variable-through-azure-start-up-task.aspx) and now I'm at a loss of what to do. 
Are the following possible:
1. Accessing the role environment from inside the executable somehow?
2. Passing the setting value to the script as a parameter?

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to move the app setting from the service configuration to blob storage from where it is accessible to both the startup task and the running service.

Comment: I'd go with this solution only if there's no other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the RoleEnvironment information in a PowerShell script (which you load in the startup task) which will let you access your ServiceConfiguration settings:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime")
$mySetting = [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment]::GetConfigurationSettingValue("MySetting")

if($mySetting -eq "True"){ .....}
```

In my ServiceConfiguration (.cscfg) I have a setting called MySettig which is True/False.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same from the executable? We decided to go with an executable and not a script to avoid messing with the execution policy on the machine.

Comment: Seems like referencing the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime assembly from my executable gave me access to the app settings I needed. Thanks for the help.